# Magento - How to get data from custom MySQL table in Adminhtml grid table

Tags: php, mysql, magento, admin, adminhtml

I'm using Magento 1.9.0.1!

Right now i am working on a custom magento extension.
I want to display data from a custom MySQL table to my custom page in HTML grid table.

Here are all files which i've created to achieve this.

In my /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
        <smsnotification>
            <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource</resourceModel>
        </smsnotification>
        <vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource>
        <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <smsnotification>
            <table>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification</table>
            </smsnotification>
        </entities>
        </vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <smsnotification_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                 <use>core_setup</use>
             </connection>
        </smsnotification_setup>
        <smsnotification_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </smsnotification_read>
        <smsnotification_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </smsnotification_write>
    </resources>    
    <events>
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <vivasindustries_smsnotification>
                    <class>smsnotification/observer</class>
                    <method>orderSaved</method>
                </vivasindustries_smsnotification>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events>
    <helpers>
        <smsnotification>
            <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Helper</class>
        </smsnotification>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <smsnotification>
             <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block</class>
        </smsnotification>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <vivas>
                                        <title>Vivas - All</title>
                                    </vivas>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification before="Mage_Adminhtml">VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Adminhtml</VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

In my /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Status.php:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Status extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_blockGroup = 'smsnotification';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_sales_status';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Send SMS on Order Status Changes');

        parent::__construct();
        $this->_removeButton('add');
    }
}
```

In my /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Status/Grid.php:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Status_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('smsnotification_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('increment_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
            ->join(array('a' => 'sales/order_address'), 'main_table.entity_id = a.parent_id AND a.address_type != \'billing\'', array(
                'city'       => 'city',
                'country_id' => 'country_id'
            ))
            ->join(array('c' => 'customer/customer_group'), 'main_table.customer_group_id = c.customer_group_id', array(
                'customer_group_code' => 'customer_group_code'
            ))
            ->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
                'fullname',
                'CONCAT({{customer_firstname}}, \' \', {{customer_lastname}})',
                array('customer_firstname' => 'main_table.customer_firstname', 'customer_lastname' => 'main_table.customer_lastname'))
            ->addExpressionFieldToSelect(
                'products',
                '(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(\' \', x.name)
                    FROM sales_flat_order_item x
                    WHERE {{entity_id}} = x.order_id
                        AND x.product_type != \'configurable\')',
                array('entity_id' => 'main_table.entity_id')
            )
        ;

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        parent::_prepareCollection();
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $helper = Mage::helper('smsnotification');
        $currency = (string) Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE);

        $this->addColumn('increment_id', array(
            'header' => $helper->__('Order #'),
            'index'  => 'increment_id'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('purchased_on', array(
            'header' => $helper->__('Purchased On'),
            'type'   => 'datetime',
            'index'  => 'created_at'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('products', array(
            'header'       => $helper->__('Products Purchased'),
            'index'        => 'products',
            'filter_index' => '(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(\' \', x.name) FROM sales_flat_order_item x WHERE main_table.entity_id = x.order_id AND x.product_type != \'configurable\')'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('fullname', array(
            'header'       => $helper->__('Name'),
            'index'        => 'fullname',
            'filter_index' => 'CONCAT(customer_firstname, \' \', customer_lastname)'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('city', array(
            'header' => $helper->__('City'),
            'index'  => 'city'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('country', array(
            'header'   => $helper->__('Country'),
            'index'    => 'country_id',
            'renderer' => 'adminhtml/widget_grid_column_renderer_country'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('customer_group', array(
            'header' => $helper->__('Customer Group'),
            'index'  => 'customer_group_code'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
            'header'        => $helper->__('Grand Total'),
            'index'         => 'grand_total',
            'type'          => 'currency',
            'currency_code' => $currency
        ));

        $this->addColumn('shipping_method', array(
            'header' => $helper->__('Shipping Method'),
            'index'  => 'shipping_description'
        ));

        $this->addColumn('order_status', array(
            'header'  => $helper->__('Status'),
            'index'   => 'status',
            'type'    => 'options',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
        ));

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportInchooCsv', $helper->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportInchooExcel', $helper->__('Excel XML'));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }
}
```

**This `Grid.php` file is taken from the guide from here: http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/ and some edits from this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54897/how-to-get-data-from-custom-mysql-table-into-your-adminhtml-grid-table/54898#54898**

Let me show you the structure and the data i want to show in the grid table:

[image]

The next 3 files are created because i was told so in this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54897/how-to-get-data-from-custom-mysql-table-into-your-adminhtml-grid-table/54898#54898

Here is what i have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Model/SmsNotification.php:

```
<?php
class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model_Smsnotification extends extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('smsnotification/smsnotification');
    }

}
```

In my /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Model/Resource/Smsnotification.php:

```
<?php
class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model_Resource_Smsnotification extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('smsnotification/smsnotification','id');
    }
}
```

In my /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Model/Resource/Smsnotification/Collection.php:

```
<?php 
class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model_Resource_Smsnotification_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract{
    protected function _constuct(){
        $this->_init('smsnotification/smsnotification');    
    }
}
```

**My question is what i have to change in my `Grid.php` file so this table will show the data from the table `VivasIndustries_SmsNotification` only ?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What data is it showing currently that is not in the table `VivasIndustries_SmsNotification`?

Answer (score 0):

In your /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Status/Grid.php change the _prepareCollection function:

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {
    $collection = Mage::getModel("smsnotification/smsnotification")->getCollection();
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```